# Find out if nested ng-repeat displayed anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation where I have a nested `ng-repeat` and I need to figure out if the inner `ng-repeat` actually did display anything or if nothing was shown. And if nothing was shown, display a message saying there was nothing to display:

```
<div ng-repeat="area in $ctrl.specTplAreas">
    <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items track by $index" 
       ng-if="item.specTemplateGroupId === area.id">displaying an item</div>
    <div ng-if="inner div above had no items to display">There are no items to display</div>
</div>
```

How can I track if the nested `ng-repeat` displayed anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Controller filter out items that doesn't match

```
$scope.items = $scope.items.filter(function (item) {
    return $scope.specTplAreas.find(function (area) {
        return area.id == item.specTemplateGroupId;
    })
});
```

now in `items` you will have only the items you want to display

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items track by $index>
        Items are there
</div>
<div ng-hide="$ctrl.items.length"> Items are not there</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="area in $ctrl.specTplAreas"
    <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items track by $index>
       <div ng-if="item.specTemplateGroupId === area.id"> Items are there</div>
       <div ng-if="item.specTemplateGroupId !== area.id"> Items are not there</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm. It prints out "Items are not there" many times when it should print once. Because there are many items but they just have the wrong specTemplateGroupId. Can we get that to just print once, and not for every item?

Comment: Yes since you are placing inside ng-repeat. you could actually check it outside the ng-repeat

Comment: Then we lose access to the `item` variable

Comment: what is the requirement?

Comment: To display a message if the inner div above (the second div in the question) did not display anything.

Comment: I am asking the business requirement so that I can create a demo

Comment: What do you need to know that is not in the question?

Comment: Haha! I am trying to help you! The question you have posted does not have enough information , in addition the code I provided should work with small tweak

Comment: Just loop through two lists in the way I have posted in the question. In the second loop, if `item.specTemplateGroupId === area.id` then display "displaying an item", but if nothing gets displayed there, display "There are no items to display"

Comment: ok then create a function in your controller, which checks for the specificed condition in your array and return true or false and bind the function in ng-if

Comment: It not a good solution to call a method inside ng-repeat. I would rather change the data or structure of data